# Laravel request validator redirect with errors

Tags: php, laravel, validation, request

I would like to make a validator through the usage of Laravel requests, and validation is working fine. But if I don't do them in the controller I can't return back to view with errors if validator fails.

Is it possible to implement this:

```
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('post/create')
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
    }
```

within the custom request? Something like this maybe:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    ]; // ->withErrors()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FormRequest by default returns the user back to the previous page with the errors and input. You don't have to specify it manually. Just set the rules and use the newly created `FormRequest` in your controller method instead of using the `Request` object.

This is what happens under the hood.

```
return $this->redirector->to($this->getRedirectUrl())
            ->withInput($this->except($this->dontFlash))
            ->withErrors($errors, $this->errorBag);
```